# Loading gif when page is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to display user a loading gif when JS do something.

Before I start I would like to say i found multiple articles about this theme but noone of them helped me.

- I found multiple using interceptor (e.g. [this](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/displaying-a-loading-spinner.html) or [this](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/displaying-a-loading-spinner.html))
- Also found some with single controller / directive (e.g. [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/AI1z21?p=preview))

**What I want:**
I would like to make something more complex. So any controller or any directive can have access to change loading status and display it.

**What did i try:**

I start with making a `LoadingService` to give access to change status from anywhere:

```
myApp.service('LoadingService', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
        var loading = false;

        this.isLoading = function() {
            return loading;
        };

        this.stopLoading = function() {
            // loading will be visible at least 1s
            $timeout(function () {
                loading = false;
                console.log(loading);
            }, 1000);
        };

        this.startLoading = function() {
            loading = true;
            console.log(loading);
        }
}]);
```

After that I create an `HeaderCtrl` where I want to display loading gif by default:

```
myApp.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoadingService', function ($scope, LoadingService) {
    $scope.isLoading = LoadingService.isLoading();
}]);
```

And then in my other controller I try to start and stop

```
LoadingService.startLoading();
// Some code between
LoadingService.stopLoading();
```

**What's actualy happening:**

Nothing, to be more specific, the value of loading is changing from `false` to `true` and then back to `false` but image is not showing.

**Example:**
I know it can be pretty complex problem so I create an live example which can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/43HdyLBB9ri0s6yQbJ8X?p=preview

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: when you call `LoadingService.isLoading();` it only returns the value of the variable at that moment, there will be no inheritance when the variable is updated later

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the value of isLoading to scope.isLoading, set the function itself. Then call it in the template.

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4iq8MBQNB43kIeezM40n?p=preview)

```
myApp.directive("loader", ['LoadingService', function(LoadingService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        // templateUrl: 'src/templates/loader.html',
        template: '<div ng-if="isLoading()">LOADER</div>',
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.isLoading = LoadingService.isLoading;
        }
    }
```